# Source code doesn't match byte code IntelliJ 15 while debugging

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am facing a issue while debugging Java code in IntelliJ.

I am connected to remote server, Am using Maven to build my project and project is building properly, verified it multiple times.

Every time I insert a debug point, IntelliJ returns an error message "**there is no executable code at that point**". While some breakpoints are inserted, IntelliJ returns a error message while execution "**source code doesn't match byte code**".

Tried solution provided in various links like : using synchronize options, invalidate caches, rebuilding and others.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the source code you have in IDE corresponds to the classes loaded in the remote JVM? It could be that you have some extra jar in the classpath with older class versions that overrides the more recent versions or the code is built without debug info, or some annotation processors or obfucsators have changed the target classes during the build process.

Comment: Sometimes it happens when you have newer version of your project in maven, but local version is outdated. Try `Settings->Maven->Reimport project` and see what happens.

Comment: **Anton**, I tried what you mentioned and though I didn't see an option Reimport project, enabled the option Always update snapshot. But there was no success. Earlier I had opened multiple projects built in same repo in a single window of IntelliJ, now I tried to open single project, no success as well.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, I went through what you suggested and decompiled jar in my JVM and compared it with my source code. I found that there was a mismatch and then i checked the git branch of the source code and code present in JVM, it was of different git branches of same repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make absolutely sure that the source code you have in IDE corresponds to the classes loaded in the remote JVM.

It could be that you have some extra jar in the classpath with older class versions that overrides the more recent versions or the code is built without debug info, or some annotation processors/obfuscators have changed the target classes during the build process.

Using `javap` or a decompiler can help to detect classes that are not in sync.

As you have mentioned in the comment, the code running on the server was from the different git branch than the code you had in IDE. This could be avoided by rebuilding the project in IDE and deploying the actual code to the server.

Comment: Is it possible to get byte code from the server debugging on remote with IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: @rilaby no, it's not possible.